# Umbraco 7 route to custom Controller for rest API

Tags: json, xml, umbraco, umbraco7

i want to map a Route to an ApiController, to post data to it.
I'm not using a Surface contoller, since i want a clean url like `/api/test/{action}`, without the `umbraco/surface` part in url.

I'm trying to use

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "ApiTest",
    "Api/Test/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Api_Test",
        action = "Search"
    });
```

But i'm getting an error since MapHttpRoute need a 4th string[] parameter.

How can i Map that route?
Then i will post a **json** or **xml** and return the response (json or xml).

Comment: Why you're not using UmbracoApiController with auto routing already applied? https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

Comment: Because i don't want the `/Umbraco/` in the Url

Comment: Fair enough. Check this: https://www.andreasjohansson.eu/technical-blog/configuring-custom-web-api-routing-for-umbraco-sites/ but ignore points 3+ and replace it with just a simple EventHandler with overrides. It should do it's job.

Answer (score 1):

Use RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute instead. I've used that previously in Umbraco sites and it works fine, e.g.

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                name: "cookie-api-location",
                url: "cookie-api/setregioncheckcookie/",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Cookie",
                    action = "SetRegionCheckCookie"
                }
            );
```